# Reduce a matrix to row-echelon form with partial pivoting

Tags: linear-algebra

> Use the Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting manually
>   to reduce the following matrix to row echelon form:
>
> $$
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>         -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>         -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>         -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
>         -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $$

I did the following operations:

1. $R_2 \to R_2 – (\frac{a_{kj}}{a_{ij}})R_1$ where $a_{ij} \neq 0, k > i$ and $i, k$ are rows.
2. $R_2 \leftrightarrow R_4$
3. $R_3 \to R_3 – (\frac{a_{kj}}{a_{ij}})R_2$
4. $R_3 \leftrightarrow R_5$
5. $R_3 \to R_3 – (\frac{a_{kj}}{a_{ij}})R_2$
6. $R_3 \leftrightarrow R_4$
7. $R_2 \to R_2 – (\frac{a_{kj}}{a_{ij}})R_1$
8. $R_3 \to R_3 – (\frac{a_{kj}}{a_{ij}})R_2$

So, the resultant matrix is:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 2 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

If my calculations are correct, can I claim that I reduced the matrix correctly? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you just add row 1 to all other row? Can you see a nice pattern emerging?

Comment: The leftmost column will be all zeros except the entry $(1, 1)$ which is $1$ and the rightmost one will be all twos except for $(1, 5)$ which is $1$? If that's correct, do we swap any rows?

Comment: You have cleared the first column. Is there any reason to be unhappy with the pivot in position (2,2)? Apart from the changes to the last column then new 4 by 4 lower right corner of your matrix is very similar to the original matrix!

Comment: I see the pattern, but I am not seeing why we should use partial pivoting here which calls for row swapping?

Comment: Precisely! There is no need for you to pivot in this problem. You can (correctly) say that you used Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting, but that discovered along the way that you did not need to actually pivot.

Comment: Thank you very much @CarlChristian.

Comment: I forgot to ask. Since the row-echelon form is not unique, is it possible to approach this problem a bit differently and end up using partial pivoting?

Comment: Yes. If we decided to (arbitrarily) scale a row during the process we could engineer a situation where the current diagonal entry was not the best possible pivot. Your current problem is a stand-alone problem with no underlying real world application. In applications from the real world there can be good reason to scale the rows/columns of the matrices involved, before one does Gaussian elimination. This is done in an effort to reduce the condition number of the matrix. But this is a topic for another day :)

Answer (score 0):

[ Please do not up vote: question was answered to OP's apparent satisfaction by discussion in comments. This answer summarises comments to prevent the question turning up in lists of questions with no answers]

OP's gaussian elimination to row echelon form was correct. Additionally, the elimination may be done in a different way to avoid pivoting.